# Filter products from a specific custom meta data in Woocommerce shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, product

I need to filter the WooCommerce shop page and only want to display products which expects a custom product meta data. This is what I've found in the `archive-product.php`:

```
/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop.
 *
 * @hooked wc_print_notices - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
 * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
woocommerce_product_loop_start();
if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
         *
         * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    }
}
woocommerce_product_loop_end();
```

So how can I pass filter values in this part to only show the products with meta key X and value Y?

**Update**

I've tried it the way Loic said but when I check more then one meta value it's causing problems and I can't see any products:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'show_only_products_with_specific_metakey', 10, 2 );
function show_only_products_with_specific_metakey( $meta_query, $query ) {
    // Only on shop pages
    if( ! is_shop() ) return $meta_query;

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => '_the_meta_key',
        'value'   => 'the_value',
        'compare' => 'EXIST'
    );

    //Don't works when adding the second one
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => '_the_meta_key',
        'value'   => 'the_value_2',
        'compare' => 'EXIST'
    );


    return $meta_query;
};
```

I've two products:

- Product A -> Has `the_value_2`
- Product B -> Has `the_value`

So I'm expecting these two products here. When I remove the second `meta_query` I'm getting only product B.

Comment: means? question is not clear

Comment: So how can I pass filter values in this part to only show the products with meta key X and value Y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom function hooked in `woocommerce_product_query_meta_query` filter hook, where you will replace `_the_meta_key` in the code below, by your targeted `meta_key`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'show_only_products_with_specific_metakey', 10, 2 );
function show_only_products_with_specific_metakey( $meta_query, $query ) {
    // Only on shop pages
    if( ! is_shop() ) return $meta_query;

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => '_the_meta_key',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS'
    );
    return $meta_query;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

---

**Addition (related to your last comment):**

To make it work for multiple meta values you need to use **`'compare' => 'IN'`**, like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'show_only_products_with_specific_metakey', 10, 2 );
function show_only_products_with_specific_metakey( $meta_query, $query ) {
    // Only on shop pages
    if( ! is_shop() ) return $meta_query;

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => '_the_meta_key',
        'value'     => array('L','XL'),
        'compare' => 'IN'
    );
    return $meta_query;
}
```

Code goes in the function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

[WP meta_query documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/)

Comment: Is there a way to do it in the archive-product file directly? Because I'm using this in my template and override it with a lot of functions but I don't get this part. So thank you a lot for your help but it would be more helpful if you can show me the way to do it directly in the file. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Mr.Jo This is about a WC_Query / WP_Query, so I don't see how you can manipulate the loop in this template. Remember that templates are mostly useful to make changes in the html structure output or in the code when nothing else is available.

Comment: I've a problem with this. I'm trying to check multiple values here so for example get product with meta value L & XL. But it looks like that this don't work with two values because when I create a second meta_query it don't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );`

```
function ctm_loop_53631963(){
    global $post;
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_value_key')
    if($meta !== 'desired_value'){
        continue;
    }
}

do_action('woocommerce_shop_loop', 'ctm_loop_53631963');
```

read more about wordpress actions [Plugin API/Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)

Comment: Don't works this way. Tried it and it wont do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete workaround from my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'mc_woocommerce_product_query_action', 10 );
function mc_woocommerce_product_query_action( $query ){
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );
    $tax_query = $query->get( 'tax_query' );

    if( !empty( $_GET['rate_type'] ) ) {
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'     => 'rate_type',
            'value'   => $_GET['rate_type'],
            'compare' => '=', // <=== Here you can set other comparison arguments
        );
    }

    if( !empty( $_GET['postcode'] ) ) {
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'     => 'auth_postcode',
            'value'   => $_GET['postcode'],
            'compare' => '=',
        );
    }

    if ( !empty( $_GET['service_type'] && $_GET['service_type'] !== '-1' ) ) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
            'field'     => 'term_id',
            'terms'     => array( $_GET['service_type'] ),
            // 'operator'  => 'IN'
        );
    }
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    
    return $query;
}
```