# Hide the children products from grouped product on Woocommerce loops

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, product

Having all the single products that are assigned to grouped products available and visible on the archive / category pages is not an ideal solution and I'm wondering how to resolve this.

I know there's a "visibility" option in WooCommerce, but that's even less ideal.

As far as I understand it, WooCommerce now uses `meta data` for this and not `post_parent` and because of that, I am asking for help on how to update this query to cover that.

The code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975262/woocommerce-only-show-grouped-products-parent-in-the-loop) that I tried and doesn't work anymore:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'hide_single_products_assigned_to_grouped_product_from_archive' );
function hide_single_products_assigned_to_grouped_product_from_archive( $q ){
    $q->set( 'post_parent', 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant really target the children products from a grouped product on the product query as  the data is stored under `_children` meta_key on `wp_post_meta` table as a serialized array.

But what you can do is first to add to all children products from your grouped products a custom field. Then you will be able to use that custom field to change the product query.

The following function will do that job and you will run it **only once**:

```
function add_a_custom_field_to_grouped_children_products() {
    // get all grouped products Ids
    $grouped_ids = wc_get_products( array( 'limit' => -1, 'type' => 'grouped', 'return' =>'ids' ) );

    // Loop through grouped products
    foreach( $grouped_ids as $grouped_id ){
        // Get the children products ids
        $children_ids = (array) get_post_meta( $grouped_id, '_children', true );

        // Loop through children product Ids
        foreach( $children_ids as $child_id ) {
            // add a specific custom field to each child with the parent grouped product id
            update_post_meta( $child_id, '_child_of', $grouped_id );
        }
    }
}
add_a_custom_field_to_grouped_children_products(); // Run the function
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Once saved, browse any page of your web site. Then remove that code and save.

---

Now all your grouped children products will have a custom field. If you add/create more grouped products, you will need the following function that will add that custom field to the children products:

```
// Add on the children products from a grouped product a custom field
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta_grouped', 'wc_action_process_children_product_meta' );
function wc_action_process_children_product_meta( $post_id ) {
    // Get the children products ids
    $children_ids = (array) get_post_meta( $post_id, '_children', true );

    // Loop through children product Ids
    foreach( $children_ids as $child_id ) {
        // add a specific custom field to each child with the parent grouped product id
        update_post_meta( $child_id, '_child_of', $post_id );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Now to finish, the function that will hide from on all product loops the children products from your grouped products:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'hide_children_from_grouped_products' );
function hide_children_from_grouped_products( $meta_query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() ) {
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'     => '_child_of',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        );
    }
    return $meta_query;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [Filter products from a specific custom meta data in Woocommerce shop page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53631542/filter-products-from-a-specific-custom-meta-data-in-woocommerce-shop-page/53636032#53636032)

Comment: After running the functions three times, the change "kicked in". Thank you so much for taking the time to review and fix this. I truly appreciate it.

Comment: You need to run the function on init action, because it is not guaranteed that woocommerce is fully loaded. add_action( 'init', 'add_a_custom_field_to_grouped_children_products' );